# buildroot using external toolchain - rootfilesystem creating

Tags: gcc, buildroot

I am trying to build my own rootfile system for RPI using buildroot.
I am new to buildroot.

I have downloaded following cross compiler folder from git :--
https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian
as mentioned in this link :--
http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/

How i will come to know what is the kernel header is used by above cross compiler ?

My installer GCC compiler is :--
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

crosscompiler is downloaded from git at following location:--
~/home/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian

Please suggest what value to fill here for toolchain selection :--

```
Toolchain type : External toolchain
Toolchain : Custom toolchain
Toolchain origin : Pre-installed toolchain
Toolchain path : ?
Toolchain prefix : ?
external Toolchain kernel header series : ?
external toolchain c library : ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mention the path of the cross compiler

Also mention the prefix. Since you are using arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc your prefix is arm-linux-gnueabihf

external toolchain library : eglibc

Comment: Path of cross compiler :--  /home/katoch/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin .. so you mean to say this i should put as the path... ?

Comment: what about toolchain kernel header series & toolchain c library ?

Comment: kernel header series should be the one you are using in your pc example 3.11.x

Comment: You mean to say ... Of my crosscompiler ?

Comment: Kernel headers series should definitely *NOT* be the one you are using on your PC. It should be the version of the kernel that is used in the cross-compiler.

Comment: yes I was mentioning the cross compiler only try to find from the sysroot with which it was built

Comment: Thanks for the reply ...  I will use Sourcery CodeBench 2014.05 for time being.